# Close connection PDO

Tags: php, mysql, class, pdo

I am using [PHP-MySQL-PDO-Database-Class](https://github.com/indieteq/PHP-MySQL-PDO-Database-Class) / [Db.class.php](https://github.com/indieteq/PHP-MySQL-PDO-Database-Class/blob/master/Db.class.php) for my project but I am not able to close connection in this.

Here is what I am trying:

```
$HPSB = new SelectModel();
$HPSB->Find('1');
echo $HPSB->model;
$Close = new DB();
echo $Close->CloseConnection();// Connection should get close here
echo $HPSB->id;// but i am getting output here also so connection is not closed
```

Please help

Comment: Maybe you have the object still filled in memory($HPSB)...try before close the connection: unset($HPSB);

Comment: Looks at me as if you just close the newly created $Close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection remains active for the lifetime of that PDO object.

To close the connection, you need to destroy the object by ensuring that all remaining references to it are 
assign NULL to the variable that holds the object.

```
$HPSB = null
```

If you don't do this explicitly, PHP will automatically close the connection when your script ends.